# Change color of back button in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Cannot change the color of my back button in android. In ios, is working very well.

```
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BackgroundColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["white"];
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["white"];
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["texto"];
```

Expected: back button color black.

Actual result: back button color white.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5177), it currently isn't supported and there is an issue open on GitHub. For now, you should use a custom renderer or define a theme in your styles.

Comment: Nice. 
You think that in the next update, it will already be solved?

Comment: @RafaVieira I do not think so the xamarin team is busy with other priority things as of now this is the least of their problems! And to change the back button colour you do not need a custom renderer just change the theme properly and it should work!

Comment: I have a global theme, but my search page has a toolbar with a white background. And so, my back button on all pages is blank, my back button "disappears" in that page.

Comment: @RafaVieira then define a particular theme for that activity?

Answer (score 0):

Add a ToolbarTheme style in your Android project *Resources/layout/styles.xml*

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Then add `android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"` to your Toolbar in *Resources/layout/Toolbar.axml*